# How to dynamically change an html element in android webview

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin, webview

[https://www.bing.com/search?q=кму](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%BC%D1%83)
here I need to change the bing icon to google
I tried :

```
 if (url == "https://www.bing.com/search?q=")
    {
        view.evaluateJavascript(
            ("\n"+
                    "windows.addEventListener(load, (event) => {\n" +
                    "  let \"style\" = document.head.appendChild(document.createElement(style));\n" +
                    "  style.innerHTML =\".b_logo:after\" {content:url(https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_light_color_92x30dp.png);\n" +
                    "  };\n"+
                    "!important;\n"+
                     "});"),
            null
        )
    }
```

I started it here : override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {

I also tried :

```
view.loadDataWithBaseURL("baseURL", "htmlString", "text/html", "UTF-8", null)
        val htmlString = "<html><body><.b_logo:after='https://www.bing.com/rp/tfpoqzYv42r7UjQvzw0PVIoT2nY.png'></body></html>"
        val newHTMLString = htmlString.replace("<.b_logo:after=\"'https://www.bing.com/rp/tfpoqzYv42r7UjQvzw0PVIoT2nY.png'>", "<.b_logo:after='https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_light_color_92x30dp.png'>")
        view.loadDataWithBaseURL("baseURL", newHTMLString, "text/html", "UTF-8", null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure your Javascript code runs after the page has been loaded.

And in order to ensure this, you can create your own `WebViewClient` and implement [this method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)):

```kotlin
override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?)
```

> **Notify the host application that a page has finished loading.** This method is called only for main frame. Receiving an onPageFinished() callback does not guarantee that the next frame drawn by WebView will reflect the state of the DOM at this point. In order to be notified that the current DOM state is ready to be rendered, request a visual state callback with WebView#postVisualStateCallback and wait for the supplied callback to be triggered.

For example, you may have something like this:

```kotlin
fun initWebView() {
    val webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.wvTest)
    webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
            // This callback function is triggered after the page is loaded
            val javascript = ... // Your Javascript function here
            view?.evaluateJavascript(javascript) {
                // You can log if there is any value returned after running the Javascript code
            }
        }
    }
    webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.bing.com/search?q=кму")
}
```

And of course you have to also make sure your Javascript function is really working on the corresponding page.